Obsidian, Core Plug-in, Insert Unique File, Error Message, Folder Not Found. Any fixes?
Utilizing the Insert Unique File plug-in in Obsidian. Copying the path that shows in lower left when I hover over the active vault. I get Error Message that folder where I want to insert file is Not Found.
Any others experiencing this problem and potential fixes?
Tried checking Perplexity.ai. Tried putting in relative path, i.e. ./Vault (of 241104). Did not help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
